# Raven DB to SQL server (NoSQL DB to Relational DB)

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, ravendb, database, nosql

Is there a way to convert/migrate NoSQL database data(Raven,Mongo,Couch
) into SQL server data? Since some NoSQL databases lack reporting tools, would be easier if I could move the data to SQL and work off that directly (just for data analysis, querying, reporting needs).Comments appreciated.

Comment: You're right, this is the recommended way of doing reporting in RavenDB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Ravendb you have the possibility to replicate an index to a table on a SQL server. See http://ravendb.net/bundles/index-replication

In common you have to 'map' your schema-less data to the database-schema.

Comment: This might also be of interest; http://ayende.com/blog/4637/ravendb-replicating-to-a-relational-database

Answer (score 0):

Use some exchange format like `CSV`. Most database systems support `CSV` export/import through some command line tools. Otherwise you have to write your own migration script.